# How can I make a grouped bar chart for this dataframe in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

This is What I want to create using ggplot in R?
[image]

[image: This is my dataframe]

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/48-grouped-barplot-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: You might check this: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html

Answer (score 2):

I would reshape the data frame so the values are together using the reshape package and the function melt. That way it's in a form to separate by factor.

```
test <- data.frame(month = ("jan", "feb", "march", "april"), a = 1:4, b = 5:8)
test2 <- reshape2::melt(test)

test2$month <- factor(test2$month, levels = c("jan", "feb", "march","april"))

ggplot(test2, aes(x = month, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]